# h5pyのImportErrorについて

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, tensorflow, keras

学習済みモデルのdeep-learning-modelsのinception_v3.pyを実行すると下記のようなエラーが発生しました。

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "inception_v3.py", line 400, in <module>
model = InceptionV3(include_top=True, weights='imagenet')
File "inception_v3.py", line 386, in InceptionV3
model.load_weights(weights_path)
File "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 2646, in load_weights
raise ImportError('load_weights requires h5py.')
ImportError: load_weights requires h5py.
```

pip listでh5pyがインストールされていることは確認できたのですがpython対話モードで確認すると

```
import h5py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/h5py/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
from . import _errors
ImportError: libhdf5_serial.so.100: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

とインポートできませんでした。
下記コマンドで再度インストールし直しましたが結果が同じでした。

```
pip3 uninstall h5py
pip3 install --no-cache-dir h5py
```

どうすればh5pyインポートできるのでしょうか？

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/119902

Comment: マルチポスト　https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q13188402008

Answer (score 2):

エラーの内容からすると、libhdf5-serial のライブラリーがないということなので、それをインストールしてみてください。

Ubuntuであれば、以下のコマンドでインストールできます。

```
sudo apt-get install libhdf5-serial-dev
```

Comment: 出来ました。てっきり仮想環境内にlibhdf5を入れるものだとばかり思っていて、pipで頑張っていました。ありがとうございます。